# Regex match contents between tags where contents have certain text

Tags: regex, tags

Haystack:

```
<test 00>
    Don't match
</test>
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
<test 01>
    Don't match
</test>
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
<test 10>
    MATCH ME
</test>
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
<test 11>
    Don't match
</test>
```

---

Goal: I'm trying to match

```
<test 10>
    MATCH ME
</test>
```

---

The regex I've ended up using is `<test[^>]*?>(.|\n)+?MATCH ME(.|\n)+?</test>`. My problem is that my expression is returning the following

```
<test 00>
    Don't match
</test>
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
<test 01>
    Don't match
</test>
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
asdasdasdasdasdasdasda
<test 10>
    MATCH ME
</test>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
<test[^>]*>(?:(?!<test[^>]*>)[\S\s])*MATCH ME(.|\n)+?<\/test>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qO4aX0/5)

**OR**

Use negative lookahead along with DOTALL modifier `(?s)`,

```
(?s)<test[^>]*>(?:(?!<test[^>]*>).)*?MATCH ME.+?<\/test>
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qO4aX0/6)

Comment: Works nicely, thank you very much for the quick answer.